# How to connect to SPIKE Prime Hub via Bluetooth Web API and send code?

Tags: spike-prime

I am trying to go under the hood of the Bluetooth connectivity of the SPIKE Prime Hub as a demo for some kids. I managed to figure out how to use the [Bluetooth Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice) to connect to a Bluetooth device. However, after this I don't know how I can send Python code to the hub to be run.

Note that I am aware of libraries like Pybricks that do this, and that's an amazing library. I am doing this more for educational purposes. My understanding is that the [LEGO Education SPIKE web app does this as well](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/lego-education-spike-web-bluetooth-web-serial), and was just trying to implement a very basic version.

Comment: There is information on [the BLE wireless protocol used by LEGO](https://lego.github.io/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs/) available. It might be overwhelming but maybe it can help you.